# best way to import coorodinates from a .txt to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

anyone know the best way to import a .txt file with longitude and latitude coorodinates into mysql.

the coorodinates are like -0.08603880764133631,51.493810310833105. only seperated by a comma to show long and lat and the mysql table has longitude and latitude in differnt columns. or if anyone knows how to seperate them properly that would work.there are over 70000 corodinates in list so doing them manually would take to long.

Comment: Is each pair on a separate line of the .txt file?

Comment: Please give an example of a few lines of your text file.

Comment: -0.086027,51.493884
    -0.087161,51.494067
    -0.087461,51.4941
    -0.091801,51.49418
    -0.091667,51.494212
    -0.086688,51.49433

Comment: Check into [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: You have multiple lat/lng pairs on a single line?  And no other columns (such as city names)?

Answer (score -1):

If each pair is on a separate line you could easily use a regular expression search and replace looking for the beginning of line to the comma for the first part and from the comma to the end of the line for the second part.

There are also sites that will do this for you such as [scriptify.org](http://scriptify.org). This is an older site so there are probably much better ones nowadays. I'm also not sure how it will handle 7000 lines. Basically you put in your variables such as `$x, $y` in the upper box. Copy and paste your coordinates in the middle box. And lastly put your desired mysql code such as: `insert into mytable values($x, $y);`. Click on the scriptify button and it does the work for you.